# OpenGL/GLFW C++ program doesn't draw anything

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

So, I made this program that has three main files:

- a main.cpp file, which contains the program itself
- one which contains GLObject class, which is the base class for every object
- one that contains the Ellipse class, a derivated object

While I was implementing the object class (before I only had the ellipse one, then I decided to make a rectangle and found some pieces in common) I run into a problem, which is that in the screen nothing appears.

The GLObject.cpp contains the definitions of the "GLObjectsInit()" functions, which sets up the drawing program (draw_program) and all the offsets and matrix strides of the unfiorm block declared inside that program.

```
void GLObjectsInit()
{
    CompileDrawProgram(); // Compiles the draw_program

    coord_loc = glGetAttribLocation(draw_program, "coord");
    color_loc = glGetAttribLocation(draw_program, "color");

    static const GLchar* uniformNames[4] = {
        "TransformBlock.res",
        "TransformBlock.tsl",
        "TransformBlock.rot",
        "TransformBlock.scale"
    };
    GLuint uniformIndices[4];
    glGetUniformIndices(draw_program, 4, uniformNames, uniformIndices);

    GLint uniformOffsets[4];
    GLint matrixStrides[4];
    glGetActiveUniformsiv(draw_program, 4, uniformIndices, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, uniformOffsets);
    glGetActiveUniformsiv(draw_program, 4, uniformIndices, GL_UNIFORM_MATRIX_STRIDE, matrixStrides);

    resolution_offset = uniformOffsets[0];
    translation_offset = uniformOffsets[1];
    rotation_matrix_offset = uniformOffsets[2];
    rotation_matrix_stride = uniformOffsets[2];
    scale_offset = uniformOffsets[3];
}
```

Drawing program:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 450 core
in vec4 coord;
in vec4 color;
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform TransformBlock
{
    vec4 res;
    vec4 tsl;
    vec4 scale;
    mat4 rot;
} trs;

out vec4 color_vs;
void main(void)
{
    color_vs = color;
    gl_Position = ((coord * trs.scale * trs.rot) + trs.tsl) * trs.res;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 color;
in vec4 color_vs;

void main(void)
{
    color = color_vs;
}
```

The .h files contains only the headers to include and the declaration of some static variables (declared as static in order to avoid a multiple definition error):

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static GLuint draw_program;

static GLuint coord_loc, color_loc;
static GLuint resolution_offset, translation_offset, scale_offset;
static GLuint rotation_matrix_offset, rotation_matrix_stride;
```

The ellipse object has some methods to modify the object position and scale and also has a draw() method (I will write only the draw() method and the constructor function, because I don't think the other ones are involved in the problem).

Ellipse.h:

```
#include "GLObject.h"

class Ellipse//: public GLObject
{
protected:
    GLuint points_buffer, uniforms_buffer, vao;
    vertex* points;
    unsigned int size;
    bool fill;

    double ang;
    glm::mat4 rotation_matrix;
    glm::vec4 center, scale;

public:
    void Draw();

    //Other methods

    Ellipse(double w, double h, glm::vec4 cen, bool fill, glm::vec4 col = glm::vec4(1, 1, 1, 1));
    Ellipse(double r, glm::vec4 cen, bool fill, glm::vec4 col = glm::vec4(1, 1, 1, 1)) :
        Ellipse(r, r, cen, fill, col) {}

    ~Ellipse();
};
```

Ellipse.cpp:

```
#include "Ellipse.h"
using namespace std;

void Ellipse::Draw()
{
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwGetCurrentContext();

    glUseProgram(draw_program);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, uniforms_buffer);

    int w, h;   glm::vec4 res;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &w, &h);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    if (w > h) res = glm::vec4(static_cast<float>(h) / w, 1, 1, 1);
    else       res = glm::vec4(1, static_cast<float>(w) / h, 1, 1);

    glNamedBufferSubData(uniforms_buffer, resolution_offset, sizeof(glm::vec4), &res);

    if (fill) glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size);
    else      glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, size);
}

Ellipse::Ellipse(double w, double h, glm::vec4 cen, bool fill, glm::vec4 col)
{
    // Calculate the ellipse

    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    glCreateBuffers(1, &uniforms_buffer);
    glNamedBufferStorage(uniforms_buffer, sizeof(GLfloat) * 112, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

    glCreateBuffers(1, &points_buffer);
    glNamedBufferStorage(points_buffer, sizeof(vertex) * size, points, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);
    glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, points_buffer, 0, sizeof(vertex));

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, coord_loc, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, coord_loc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(vertex, coord));
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, coord_loc);

    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, color_loc, 0);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, color_loc, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, offsetof(vertex, color));
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, color_loc);

    center = cen;   ang = 0;
    scale = glm::vec4(w, h, 1, 1);
    rotation_matrix = glm::mat4(1);

    glNamedBufferSubData(uniforms_buffer, scale_offset, sizeof(glm::vec4), &scale);
    glNamedBufferSubData(uniforms_buffer, translation_offset, sizeof(glm::vec4), &center);
    glNamedBufferSubData(uniforms_buffer, rotation_matrix_offset, sizeof(glm::mat4), &rotation_matrix[0]);
}

Ellipse::~Ellipse()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &points_buffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &uniforms_buffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    delete[] points;
}
```

The main is only that:

```
#include "Ellipse.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "Title", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    GLObjectsInit();
    Ellipse ball1(0.25, 0.25, glm::vec4(0, 0, 0.5, 1), true);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        ball1.Draw();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thought #1: You are requesting OpenGL v2.0 but are trying to make it compile and run shaders designed for OpenGL 4.5 (at least the `#version` directive suggests so).

Comment: That is quite a mountain of code to review. Can you cut that down to size, something more minimal we can inspect?

Comment: @hidefromkgb Are the glfwWindowHint() functions that specify that? cause I didn't really understand their meaning and if it is like that, how should I write? (anyway that's not the problem, cause it was previously working with that)

Comment: @tadman I tried to write only the most important things, probably the only thing I can remove is the Ellipse constructor, but then you have to trust me when I say I initialized all the buffers correctly

Comment: You specify vertex coordinates with tuple size of 4 (`x`, `y`, `z`, `w` - [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)) - `glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, coord_loc, 4, ...)`. How do you initialize the `w` component of the vertices?

Comment: When, in the main file, I call the constructor of the ellipse the first parameter is the center of the ellipse, and it's a vec4, so it uses the same w as the the one of the vector that you pass in the constructor

Comment: @RiccardoRipanti [See here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_ctx). You should rather try `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` = 4 and `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` = 5 if you really intend to use the shaders mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok @hidefromkgb, thank you, but as I expected, that was not the problem. Not trying to say your clarification was useless: I appreciate those things too, because I'd like to be, one day, a good programmer and a good programmer is precise (especially when taliking about c/c++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I finally found what the problem was:

In the GLObjects.h file I declare some variables as static, because, if I don't do so, it generates some multiple definition errors. Declaring them as static solves that problem, but creates another one, because now each file has it's own copy of those variables.

So what I did, instead, to solve the problem, is to declare those variables as extern, and then define them in the GLObject.cpp file.